# AntMatcher seems not to match requested path (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, spring-security

We are trying to use Spring Security to secure our webservice. We are using a customer filter (a class that extends `GenericFilterBean`) to read a JSON Web Token from the HTTP header. If a token exists, it is stored as `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` in the Security Context. Protected resources should use our customer Authentication Provider to verify if the token is valid and to load user info (which includes roles).

The problem is that I don't get it to configure an AntMatcher for a specific resource.
If I use `antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")` the resource is protected, but we don't want all resources to match, so I tried an AntMachter for one resource like this:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/rest/security/v1/currentuser").hasRole("USER")
```

But this matcher seems not to match the requested resource and so the Authentication Provider is not called. But I don't know why. I tried several combinations of ant pattern but nothing worked yet.

I set a breakpoint in the custom filter to check the current path and when I call `servletRequest.getPathInfo()` I get excatly what I thought it should be our ant pattern: `/rest/security/v1/currentuser`

Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .anonymous().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/rest/security/v1/currentuser").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http
        .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Custom filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    Optional<String> token = Optional.ofNullable(httpRequest.getHeader(HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_HEADER));
    if (token.isPresent()) {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken requestAuthentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(token, null);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(requestAuthentication);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

Authentication provider:

```java
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = null;

    try {

     // Token Validation, Loading User Info

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to authenticate", e);
    }

    return authenticationToken;
}
```

Comment: Sanity check: you're sure that the request is a GET request right? Your current configuration only protects those, any other type of request to the specified path can come right in.

Comment: yes, it's a GET request (before I tried without HTTP Method, but it also didn't work)

Comment: Hm, I wonder if it is to do with the pattern or with something else. To somewhat prove that, what if you use the matcher /rest/security/v1/** to secure everything under /v1 and not specify a specific HTTP method? I am kind of expecting that to also not secure anything, while it most definitely should.

Comment: At which URL is your application deployed? The ant matcher should contain the path WITHOUT the application part of the URL.

Comment: Your filter isn't calling your authentication provider, which may be part of the problem. Typically an authentication-establishing filter will call the authentication manager, which then calls the registered authentication providers. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java#L120 for an example of a filter with a similar role to yours (which you, btw, might consider using instead of your custom filter).

Comment: @Dampignak Your assumption *But this matcher seems not to match the requested resource and so the Authentication Provider is not called.* is wrong. Your filter is called anyway. But your filter is not calling the authentication manager as  jzheaux wrote in his comment. BTW: You are misusing `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`. That is for already authenticated user (for example in Tomcat).